# How to implement secure (unqueryable) login inputs with React?

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe

I'm concerned that chrome extensions can check `input.value` and retrieve the user's credentials from the HTML form

What is the best practice for averting this? I'm thinking to wrap it in an iFrame, but I vaguely remember that iFrame.contentWindow is queryable too.

Does this have to to with 'use strict'??

Any advice is appreciated, I'm obviously confused

Comment: There's nothing whatsoever you can do to secure that. If a user has installed a Chrome extension that snoops on passwords, it's their problem. Outside of all the normal web APIs, stuff that the browser decides to do is pretty much completely out of your control. (And "use strict" has absolutely nothing to do with it.)

Comment: Yea I guess keydown events would register too. wtf the web isn't safe at all

Comment: No it isn't :) You really have no way of knowing whether the client at the other end of the connection is a browser. It could be anything.